# Scrolltop animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this js to scroll to the id of the page.  I took it from w3 schools and it works on my other site, so I don't understand why it doesn't work on my new site.  It goes to the correct part of the page, but it doesn't do the scroll animation.

js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function (event) {

            if (this.hash !== "") {

                event.preventDefault();

                var hash = this.hash;


                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 900, function () {


                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

html navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sessions">SESSIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Please let me know if you need to see any other code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work.

Are you positive that the new site is using jQuery and that the IDs of the element that you are scrolling to are correct?

Is your console displaying an error?

Comment: no errors, I am using jquery, and the IDs are correct

Comment: Is there a URL you can provide?